# How to save image to hard disk without opening in new window

Tags: html, css

I have a link that leads to an image.

```
 <a href="/images/foo.png">
     <img src="/images/thumbnails/foo.png" width="27" height="25" align="absmiddle"/>
 </a>
```

How can I force a browser to save the image (like what happens when you right click a link and choose "Save As") instead of opening the image in the current window/tab?

Comment: Save what where?  What new window?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: by clicking the link.it should be download without opening

Comment: What link are you referring to?

Comment: You can use a server-side language (like PHP) to handle your image links, and then have them force a download.  You's get the "save as" dialog when you clicked the link.

Comment: @ede: In general, respond to requests for clarifications by updating your post, rather than replying with a comment. For one thing, a question should be understandable without reading comments. For another, SO is a Q&A site, not a forum, and comments aren't intended (nor are they well suited) for discussions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `HTML` markup, the `download` attribute is the only way to go:

```
<a href="http://www.example.net/picture.png" download="File_Name.png">Download</a>
```

Unfortunately, the `download` attribute is not working in most browsers.
Currently, using specific headers is the best way to go.
This needs to be done server-side, quick `PHP` example:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.pdf"');
readfile('original.pdf');
?>
```